# Configuration Page for AppCloud Content Service

Tags: eloqua

I have developed an `Eloqua AppCloud Content Service` and installed it. But when ever I try to `Edit Content` on the service instance, I see no configuration page there.

Can someone point me to a direction on how to render the edit page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit the content instance, the browser will open the configure url for the service.

Can you share your configure URL? It needs to be reachable from your browser, it is a client side call.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/AppCloud/Register/register-content.htm

EDIT from the comments:
When you click on edit the browser will call the Configure URL of the service. That URL needs to return html with the configuration page for the service.

Comment: Whenever I try to edit the browser issues a http get to a URL but the response is empty.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh When you click on edit the browser will call the Configure URL of the service. That URL needs to return html with the configuration page for the service. Which URL is it calling? What happens if you open that URL in the browser?